# open angular subroute on initial load

Tags: angular, router

If a user navigates to my angular 6 website from outside, the app will initially load the specified route page. if no path is defined it automatically navigates to the dashboard page which is fine and expected behaviour. But if a user types in for example, https://www.myapp.com/messages, the initial load still routes to the dashboard page.

If this something that can be changed? In other words, I want a user to be able to navigate directly into any subroute of my website by typing in the defined url.

Current routes in routing-module look like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  // Messaging isn't lazy loaded to allow message refreshing control
  // at app level
  {
    path: 'messages',
    component: MessagingLayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [ AuthGuard ]
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule',
    canActivate: [ AuthGuard ]
  },
  {
    path: 'cms',
    loadChildren: './cms/cms.module#CmsModule',
    canActivate: [ AuthGuard ]
  },
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'dashboard'},
  {
    path: '**',
    component: PageNotFoundComponent
  }
];
```

So to give a more detailed example, If a user comes to my site, they always find themselves at the dashboard page on the initial load. (assuming they are logged in). If they aren't logged in, then they must log in after which they are routed to the dashboard. Ideally, If someone was previously logged in (i.e. their auth token is up to date) and they navigate to the site from outside with './messages' or './cms' for example, the app would automatically route them to said page on the initial load.

Comment: Please provide details about how you implemented your routing and provide all the code relevant to that, in as short and clear a way possible. Angular routing should do the thing you want by default.

Comment: I've added some details, hopefully this helps

Comment: I have a suspicion it has to do with the AuthGuard, try removing that and see if it works. If it does work without the AuthGaurd you might want to look into how that works. I might know a way to fix that, but please do check out if it may be due to the `canActivate: [ AuthGuard ]` first

Comment: thanks, I'll try stripping that out and see if it helps

Comment: even with the canActivate route resolver commented out it still will only open the dashboard on the first load of the application

Comment: You probably have an import RouterModule somewhere try doing this `imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{enableTracing: true})]` perserve logs in your devtools and see if that gives any clues

Comment: thanks, I'll try that

Comment: I think my issue will require server-side rendering